# how to save log data using log-rotate after deploy react app by npm build & pm2 serve?

Tags: node.js, pm2, logrotate, npm-build, pm2-logrotate

I made the react app by cra in typescript. I tried to deploy by pm2, so I set the shell script like this.

**startup.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash
npm install

# Install pm2 globally
npm install -g pm2
pm2 install pm2-logrotate
pm2 set pm2-logrotate:rotateInterval 50 * * * *
pm2 set pm2-logrotate:dateFormate YYYY-MM-DD_HH-mm-ss

# Build the project in production mode
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production

# Save the pm2 process list
pm2 save


# Configure pm2 to start automatically on system boot
pm2 startup

# Generate a startup script for pm2
pm2 save


# Restart the application if it stops for any reason
pm2 resurrect

# Install serve to serve the build
npm install -g serve

# Serve the build on port 3000
pm2 --name "my-app" serve $STH_HOME/build 3000 --spa
```

so when I execute the startup.sh, then the app starts well. However, in the ecosystem.config.js, I set the data logs to be into the specific directory. But the application runs seperately.

**ecosystem.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "my-app",
      script: "node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js",
      instances: "1",
      watch: false,
      exec_mode: "cluster",
      restart_delay: "5000",
      listen_timeout: 50000,
      kill_timeout: 5000,
      out_file: "/mylogs/my-app/my-app.out",
      error_file: "/mylogs/my-app/my-app.err",
      log_date_format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
      env_development: {
        NODE_ENV: "development",
      },
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: "production",
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I expected only one app(my-app) running in my server, but there are two different my-app running in my server when I checked by `pm2 list`.

I guess that's why my log data didn't accumulate in the exact directory that I wanted. I'm aware with setting pm2 log-rotate with ecosystem.config.js is not possible.

how to store log data exact directory where I want ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the previous application first before starting the new one

```
    pm2 delete "my-app" --silent || true
```

--silent is not going to throw an error, if you do want to throw an error, don't pass the silent flag.
also, remember to save the pm2 list

```
    pm2 save --force
```

Also, I am copying your ecosystem config file, hope you don't mind :)